# jquery form name selector not working when passed as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which takes 4 parameters i.e form name, class of button , function , eventType
all i want to do is select the element button of the form and call the function accordingly but it doesnt work for me
**Works when i hard code the form name and button class**

```
registerFormEvent : function(formName,buttonClass,func,eventType) {
$('form[name= "demoForm"]').find('.submit').on(eventType,func);
```

**while it wont work when i try to pass the param into the form name and buttonClass name**

```
registerFormEvent : function(formName,buttonClass,func,eventType) {
    $('form[name= formName]').find(buttonClass).on(eventType,func);
}
```

I know its an Syntax Error but i could not find a way to do it ..help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
registerFormEvent : function(formName,buttonClass,func,eventType) {
    $('form[name="'+formName+'"]').find(buttonClass).on(eventType,func);
}
```

You need to add the formName variable outside of the the string in the selector